# how to use for loop to calculate a prime number

Tags: python, loops, sieve

```
for i in range(2, 101):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            print(i,"is a composite number")
            break
```

I tried making the `if (i%j) != 0:` but then it wouldn't work (4 is not a prime number)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. That program appears to correctly (albeit not efficiently) differentiate between prime and composite numbers.

Comment: well when I add `if (i%j) != 0: ` it dosen't work

Comment: **`if (i%j) != 0:` tests for divisibility of i by j**, specifically that i is not divisible by j. If i were divisible by j (for some 2 <= j < i), it couldn't be prime. There are [520 existing questions on \[python\] divisibility](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+divisibility+is%3Aq); this is a duplicate and should be closed; please read through the others.

Comment: I did try the others, the others wasn't what I was asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop you've used is correct for finding prime numbers. I would just another condition to it: `if i > 1:`. Also, you would want to print the prime number

```
for i in range(2, 101):
    if i > 1: # Prime numbers are greater than 1
        for j in range(2, i):
            if (i % j) == 0:
                print(i,"is a composite number")
                break
        else:
            print(i,"is a prime number")
```

Comment: if the range start at 2 the `i > 1` check becomes unnecessary though

Comment: Yes, in this case it does.

Comment: The extra `i > 1` test is unnecessary and just obfuscates. You always run a sieve starting at 2 or higher, never 1. This answer adds nothing. Also, the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

You can fix up your original algorithm like this:

```
for i in range(2, 101):
    if all([(i % j) for j in range(2, i)]):
        print(i,"is a prime number")
```

In general, you're probably better off using/learning from the established algorithms in cases like these. Here's a Python implementation of a well-known algorithm (the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) for generating the first `n` primes (credit to [tech.io](https://tech.io/playgrounds/959/python-prime-number-sieves/implementation) for the code):

```
def sieve(n):
    primes = 2*[False] + (n-1)*[True]
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5+1.5)):
        for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
            primes[j] = False
    return [prime for prime, checked in enumerate(primes) if checked]
```

Some test output:

```
print(sieve(100))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```